# Phonegap remote build

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm developing app in Sencha touch(Touch 2.4 && CMD 5) and packaging using Phonegap/Cordova for Android and iOS. I'm developing on windows machine with Android device(HTC) and iOS device(iPhone 5). 
Initially i packaged the app with cordova, and with limitation of iOS build i keep working for Android build only. I added 5 plugins (Facebook, Network Information, Camera, FIle Transfer, Email Composer) using cordova and all working fine for android build. My latest Android apk file size is 3.8 MB. 
Now i need to build iOS ipa as well, so i opted "Phonegap Remote Build Service" option. I clone my Sencha touch project and packaged it to Phonegap, added all plugins, mention the iOS platform in app.json and set remote true and add local.properties file with email and password set of paid adobe phonegap account. When i execute command "sencha app build native" , it did everything right but gave error of "Invalid email or password". Then i went for other option, i made zip file of phonegap folder and uploaded manually, and build on Adobe Phonegap Build portal, it provided me both the builds but with one big issue of huge size. Both files(apk, ipa) reached 37-40 MB.

Now i need help of different options which i can take(Other than iOS machine), how i can minimize the size of files. As locally cordova packaging providing me very lightweight apk file. If I'm doing something wrong in Phonegap packaging, please mention it.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you take a look what files take so much space? APK and IPA are just zip-archives so you can open them and investigate.

Comment: In phonegap.local.properties you might need to provide your remote build username and password as below:

# Username for PhoneGap Build
phonegap.build.remote.username=????
# Password for PhoneGap Build
phonegap.build.remote.password=????

Answer (score 0):

When you say manuall upload turns zip size to 37 - 40 MB ,i think it must contain library folder as well .

for Invalid email or password : - there must be some typo mistake only this is possible scenario i could think off.

Thanks